# Ram and cpu estimates for virtual Private server

Tags: webserver, vps

I want to transfer my website from a shared hosting to VPS. Since on a shared hosting I can not see the RAM(or CPU) usage stats, and I never used VPS or dedicated servers, so, I am not sure, what parameters to choose. My website has

1) about 350-400 thousand pageviews a month

2)~ 30 GB bandwith a month.

3) It is a usual php/mysql website. Queries are very simple. There are no joins or other  complicated queries. The main page, that is viewed the most(perhaps > 95%) contains one simple query, `SELECT id, name FROM posts WHERE name = "something"`. Table has ~ 150 K rows, and `name` column is indexed. That main page's(with most views) content is a simple text.

4) There are about 5-12 external css/js files to load.

Here, is the VPS params that Iam thinking to take(based on the price)

```
256MB RAM
256MB VSwap
1 CPU Core Access
20 GB SSD - [this one is all right]
```

Will this be about right? I know that it is very broad question, but if you can gimme some rough estimates, it will be enough.

Thanks

Comment: If you contact your provider they can tell you how much memory you normally use.    I can tell you already there is no way 256MB will be enough.  That VPS honestly is pretty well crappy.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for the reply, lemme ask on thing, even if VPS is crappy, is not it better than shared hosting ? thanks

Comment: I can't compare it to your shared hosting so I can't answer that.

Comment: @Ramhound, maybe u will be familiar, Im using dreamhost. thanks anyway :)